# XML string to xml unable to switch encoding

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, encoding

I have an XML string that is malformed.

```
DECLARE @xmlt TABLE(xstr nvarchar(max), xml xml)

INSERT INTO @xmlt(xstr) VALUES (
'  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1257" ?>
- <objects><object id="778913">a</object>
- <object id="785491">b</object>
- <object ...goes on...
- </objects>
'
```

To be able to use that XML I convert it to XML

```
UPDATE @xmlt SET xml = CAST(REPLACE(LTRIM(xstr), ' - <', '<') AS xml);
```

But I get an error 
`XML parsing: line 1, character 46, unable to switch the encoding.`

Is there any other way (without replacing the string `encoding="windows-1257"` with `""`) to convert that XML string to xml in SQL Server?

Comment: Remark: The Xml in you sample doesn't have a root node over all the <object> nodes, it's not valid

Comment: Good comment, :) thanks! The xml actually has it. Updated the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field `xstr nvarchar(max)` is not compatible with encoding windows-1257. If you use varchar(max) it won't fail at converting the string into an XML. Varchar type & Xml encoding are related. If your XML Encoding is unicoded (e.g. UFT-16) then the use of nvarchar would have worked.

This will work with your xml string:

```
DECLARE @xmlt TABLE(xstr varchar(max), xml xml)

insert into @xmlt(xstr) values( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1257"?>
- <objects>
- <object id="778913">a</object>
- <object id="785491">b</object>
- </objects>')

update @xmlt set xml = cast ( REPLACE(ltrim(xstr),' - <','<') as xml)
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230486/how-to-update-a-sql-table-column-with-xml-data