# How to update a SQL table column with XML data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Table 1:

```
id      title               chtml
0       Lopez, Michelle MD  <root><StartOne><Value1>Lopez, Michelle MD</Value1><Value2>Spanish</Value2><Value3><a title="49 west point" href="myloc.aspx?id=56" target="_blank">49 west point</a></Value3><Value4>908-783-0909</Value4><Value5><a title="CM" href="myspec.aspx?id=78" target="_blank">CM</a></Value5></StartOne></root>
1       Michael, Jogn, MD   <root><StartOne><Value1>Michael, Jogn, MD</Value1><Value2>English</Value2><Value3><a title="99 show drive" href="myloc.aspx?id=05" target="_blank">99 show drive</a></Value3><Value4>908-783-0909</Value4><Value5><a title="KM" href="myspec.aspx?id=40 target="_blank">KM</a></Value5></StartOne></root>
```

The `chtml` is of type `ntext` for id `0`:

```
<root>
    <StartOne>
        <Value1>Lopez, Michelle MD</Value1>
        <Value2>Spanish</Value2>
        <Value3>
            <a title="49 west point" href="myloc.aspx?id=56" target="_blank">49 west point</a>
        </Value3>
        <Value4>908-783-0909</Value4>
        <Value5>
            <a title="CM" href="myspec.aspx?id=78" target="_blank">CM</a>
        </Value5>
    </StartOne>
</root>
```

The `chtml` is of type `ntext` for id `1`:

```
<root>
    <StartOne>
        <Value1>Michael, Jogn, MD</Value1>
        <Value2>English</Value2>
        <Value3>
            <a title="99 show drive" href="myloc.aspx?id=05" target="_blank">99 show drive</a>
        </Value3>
        <Value4>908-783-0909</Value4>
        <Value5>
            <a title="KM" href="myspec.aspx?id=40 target="_blank">KM</a></Value5>
        </Value5>
    </StartOne>
</root>
```

`Table 2` and `Table 3` has data which is used in the creation of `Table 1` for the link Url, title, and value:

```
Table 2:

    id              title
    ---------------------------------
    56              49 west point
    90              130 chester lane
    12              320 nolan street
    05              99 show drive

Table 3:

    id              description
    ------------------------------
    78              CM
    39              IM
    40              KM
```

`Table 4` has the updated data which will be used to update `Table 1` values:

```
Table 4:

    Name                    Value2              Value3                  Value4              Value5
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Lopez, Michelle MD      English             130 chester lane        908-783-0909        KM
    Michael, Jogn, MD       Italian             320 nolan street        540-029-2090        IM
```

I am trying the following query to update one of the value:

```
declare @xml xml;
select @xml = cast([content_html] as xml)
from [myDB1].[dbo].[Table 1]

set @xml.modify('
  replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value3/text())[1]
  with "<a title="{Value3 from Table 4}" href="myloc.aspx?id={ID from Table 2 that matches the title with the title from Table 4}" target="_blank">{Value3 from Table 4}</a>"
');

-- How can I update the anchor link values of one table by querying another table data.
-- How can I update multiple fields, for Example `Value3` and `Value5`?

update [myDB1].[dbo].[Table 1]
set [content_html] = cast(@xml as nvarchar(max))
where [content_title] = 'Lopez, Michelle MD'
```

An example would be:

```
declare @xml xml;
select @xml = cast([content_html] as xml)
from [myDB1].[dbo].[Table 1]

set @xml.modify('
  replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value3/text())[1]
  with "<a title="130 chester lane" href="myloc.aspx?id=90" target="_blank">130 chester lane</a>"
');

update [myDB1].[dbo].[Table 1]
set [content_html] = cast(@xml as nvarchar(max))
where [content_title] = 'Lopez, Michelle MD'
```

Table 1 (after the above update):

```
id      title               chtml
0       Lopez, Michelle MD  <root><StartOne><Value1>Lopez, Michelle MD</Value1><Value2>Spanish</Value2><Value3><a title="130 chester lane" href="myloc.aspx?id=90" target="_blank">130 chester lane</a></Value3><Value4>908-783-0909</Value4><Value5><a title="CM" href="myspec.aspx?id=78" target="_blank">CM</a></Value5></StartOne></root>
1       Michael, Jogn, MD   <root><StartOne><Value1>Michael, Jogn, MD</Value1><Value2>English</Value2><Value3><a title="99 show drive" href="myloc.aspx?id=05" target="_blank">99 show drive</a></Value3><Value4>908-783-0909</Value4><Value5><a title="KM" href="myspec.aspx?id=40 target="_blank">KM</a></Value5></StartOne></root>
```

Please help me with the following:

- How can I update the anchor link values of one table by querying
  another table data?
- How can I update multiple fields, for Example `Value3` and `Value5`
  and then run the update statement?

Comment: your all problem can solve if we make `chtml` data type `XML` :)

Comment: @tinka I was able to fix it and make it work but the `<` is being inserted as `&lt;`

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88030/xmls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the way to solve your problem

```
declare @table4 table
(Name nvarchar(22), Value3 nvarchar(22))

    insert into @table4 values ('Lopez, Michelle MD' ,'130 chester lane')       
    insert into @table4 values ('Michael, Jogn, MD ','320 nolan street') 

declare @table1 table
(id int, title nvarchar(max), chtml ntext)


insert into @table1 values (0,'Lopez, Michelle MD',  '<root><StartOne><Value1>Lopez, Michelle MD</Value1><Value2>Spanish</Value2><Value3>
<a title="49 west point" href="myloc.aspx?id=56" target="_blank">49 west point</a></Value3><Value4>908-783-0909</Value4><Value5><a title="CM" href="myspec.aspx?id=78" target="_blank">CM</a></Value5></StartOne></root>')
insert into @table1 values (1,'Michael, Jogn, MD',   '<root><StartOne><Value1>Michael, Jogn, MD</Value1><Value2>English</Value2><Value3><a title="99 show drive" href="myloc.aspx?id=05" target="_blank">99 show drive</a></Value3><Value4>908-783-0909</Value4><Value5><a title="KM" href="myspec.aspx?id=40 target="_blank">KM</a></Value5></StartOne></root>')


declare @xml xml;
select top 1 @xml = cast(chtml as xml)
from @table1

-- How can I update the anchor link values of one table by querying another table data.
declare @titl nvarchar(22)
select @titl = Value3 from @table4 where Name = 'Lopez, Michelle MD'
set @xml.modify('
  replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value3/a/@title)[1]
  with sql:variable("@titl")
');
set @xml.modify('
  replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value3/a/text())[1]
  with sql:variable("@titl")
');

-- How can I update multiple fields, for Example `Value3` and `Value5`?
-- Answer: here you can modify Value5

update @table1
set chtml = cast(@xml as nvarchar(max))
where id = 0

select * from @table1
```

Comment: I updated what I have in the chat room. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88030/xmls

Comment: The ID in the Url also has to be the same as the ID from the table.

Comment: It is replacing the anchor with just plain text.

Comment: I have this: `set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value3/a/text())[1] with sql:variable("@locTitle")');
set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value3/a/@title)[1] with sql:variable("@locTitle")');
set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value3/a/@href)[1] with sql:variable("@locUrl")');` Thanks.

Comment: Quick question, shouldn't this line: `Set [chtml] = cast(@xml as nvarchar(max))` should be casting as `ntext` because the table that is being updated is of type `ntext`?

Comment: @SiKni8 if we directly do it then it will give an error `Explicit conversion from data type xml to ntext is not allowed` Use it `set chtml = cast(cast(@xml as nvarchar(max)) as ntext)`

Comment: One last question, if the node doesn't have any anchor link but I would like to assign it one how can I do that? without getting the &lt;? For any node really, if the anchor link doesn't exist, I would like to create it.

Comment: Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253235/how-to-use-if-else-statement-to-update-or-create-new-xml-node-entry-in-sql